# Rsyslog create two listeners (with and without TLS) with omfile as output. Possible or not?

Tags: rsyslog, rainerscript

I am trying to create a rsyslog.conf with multiple listeners e.g. with and without TLS (with streamdriver). It is possible to create multiple inputs, but as I read in the rsyslog documentation, it seems to be impossible to move the streamdriver parameters e.g. streamdriver.mode="1" from module() to inputs() or to action() when using omfile. Does anybody know if there is a way to **create multiple listeners** with **imtcp** and **omfile** as output method?

my working script for single listener:

```
# Prints every message, even if repeated 1001 times in a second. Strongly recommend for use with Splunk
$RepeatedMsgReduction off

module(load="imtcp"
    streamdriver.name="gtls" # use gtls netstream driver
    streamdriver.mode="1" # require TLS for the connection
    streamdriver.authmode="x509/name" # server is NOT authenticated
)

global(
    defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/CACertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerCertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerPrivatKeyDec.key"
)

# Create as many inputs as you like. This listens to UDP + TCP 514.
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="SplunkNetwork")


# Template for directory + filename structure. Use %FROMHOST-IP% for IP without hostname resolution
template(name="filename-by-host" type="string" string="/opt/logfiles/%FROMHOST%/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%.log")

ruleset(name="SplunkNetwork") {
        action(type="omfile" DynaFile="filename-by-host" DirCreateMode="0755" FileCreateMode="0644" DirOwner="splunk" DirGroup="splunk" FileOwner="splunk" FileGroup="splunk")
}
```

What I want to do - not working - passing the streamdriver parameters to input() or action():

```
# Prints every message, even if repeated 1001 times in a second. Strongly recommend for use with Splunk
$RepeatedMsgReduction off

module(load="imtcp")

global(
    defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/CACertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerCertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerPrivatKeyDec.key"
)

# Create as many inputs as you like. This listens to UDP + TCP 514.
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="SplunkNetwork-anon-no-tsl")
input(type="imtcp" port="1514" ruleset="SplunkNetwork-anon-tsl")


# Template for directory + filename structure. Use %FROMHOST-IP% for IP without hostname resolution
template(name="filename-by-host" type="string" string="/opt/logfiles/%FROMHOST%/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%.log")

ruleset(name="SplunkNetwork-anon-no-tsl") {
        action(type="omfile" DynaFile="filename-by-host" DirCreateMode="0755" FileCreateMode="0644" DirOwner="splunk" DirGroup="splunk" FileOwner="splunk" FileGroup="splunk" StreamDriverMode="0" StreamDriver="gtls" StreamDriverAuthMode="anon")
}

ruleset(name="SplunkNetwork-anon-tsl") {
        action(type="omfile" DynaFile="filename-by-host" DirCreateMode="0755" FileCreateMode="0644" DirOwner="splunk" DirGroup="splunk" FileOwner="splunk" FileGroup="splunk" StreamDriverMode="1" StreamDriver="gtls" StreamDriverAuthMode="anon")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

- `imtcp` for TLS
- `imptcp` for TCP

Answer (score 1):

You an use both the `imptcp` and `imtcp` modules to allow plain TCP and TLS connections. The example below shows the rsyslog configuration required to setup the logging input for plain TCP on port 514 and TLS on port 1514.

```
global(
    defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/CACertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerCertificate.pem"
    defaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/opt/splunk/etc/auth/sslCerts/ServerPrivatKeyDec.key"
)

# Load the imptcp module to provide the ability to receive messages over plain TCP
module(load="imptcp")

# Load the imtcp module to provide the ability to receive messages over TLS
module(
    load="imtcp"
    streamdriver.name="gtls" # use gtls netstream driver
    streamdriver.mode="1" # require TLS for the connection
    streamdriver.authmode="x509/name" # server is NOT authenticated
)

# Listen op port 514 (imptcp driver)
input(
    type="imptcp"
    port="514"
)

# Listen on port 1514 (imtcp driver)
input(
    type="imtcp"
    port="1514"
)
```